# Inject advertisements in pages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ads, adsense

Today I noticed that in the Chrome web store dashboard, under my extension's settings there is a check-box labeled "Ads Behavior", and whose description is "This extension injects ads into some third-party websites.".

My questions are:

- Can an ad-supported extension inject advertisements in a page visited by the user?
- If so, what is an acceptable policy?
- Can the extension replace existing advertisements (even though that seems to me kind of unethical/stealing) or must it only create new ones?
- Is it possible to use any ads network or must it be adsense?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Can an ad-supported extension inject advertisements in a page visited by the user?**

The fact the checkbox exists suggests it's acceptable as long as you declare it, so users are aware of it.

**If so, what is an acceptable policy?**

I would argue anything that makes it clear to users what you're doing and follows the terms of the ad network.

**Can the extension replace existing advertisements (even though that seems to me kind of unethical/stealing) or must it only create new ones?**

Agree it's unethical, most content and apps out there cost money and it deprives publishers. But as with a lot of extensions, it's seen by the browser as the user's choice. That's basically how the web works - users have control over the client. The most popular extensions for browsers are ad blockers, so I doubt the Chrome team would ban an extension that swapped ads. Please do consider the website owners though. Adding ads is at least better than replacing them.

**Is it possible to use any ads network or must it be adsense?**

Any, I'm fairly sure. Google wants Chrome to be seen as generally independent from its services. You'll even see Google's various competitors promoted in the Chrome Web Store at times for that reason.

***However***, there's a big caveat here. It's very possible this kind of ad injection is forbidden by the ad network in question. It's certainly the case with many affiliate links, that you can't just inject your own, or swap in your own, link. The argument is the user was already going to click on it anyway. So if you're injecting ads, the biggest constraint is going to be your ad provider, not Chrome.

Comment: I think if I will ever add ads injecting to my extension my "acceptable policy" will be to inject a number of ads proportional to the times the user uses my extension. So if the user clicks 3 times on the extension's icon -> 3 ads injected in three different pages.

Comment: @Badook, I don't see that anywhere. Btw, one question. How do I inject ads? Please let me know in detail if possible. I didn't get any useful answer to this.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to use any ads network or must it be adsense?

Actually it **can't** be AdSense. It's specifically mentionned in their [program policies](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?answer=1346295#Ads_in_a_software_application):

> *Currently, we don't permit Google ads or AdSense for search boxes to be distributed through software applications, including but not limited to, toolbars, browser extensions and desktop applications.*

I wonder if any ad provider allows such a thing.

Comment: you can always add an iframe around it and proxify content by your site, I guess... does it break policy? ... maybe... is it detectable? don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

I too had concerns about this, specifically a Chrome app extension called [Bookmark Sentry](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bdglbbcbmgnimogcmcdenggkpdmihlga) as while it does do a great job of managing your bookmarks, it also injects itself and intercepts advertisements replacing it with it's own affiliate network.

Specifically in viewing the source code it appeared to contain a 'whitelist' and 'blacklist' of sites to intercept advertising while navigating. The user is given the choice to opt-out of advertising in settings but it is poorly explained as 'marketing' with no explanation as to what it is doing.

I raised concerns to Google Chrome through flagging of abuse. Through a contact I was informed however that:

> "Ad injections are not in violation of the Chrome Web Store [program policies](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/program_policies).  The policy requires that ads must be presented in the context of the extension or, when present within another page, ads must be outside the page's normal flow and clearly state which extension they are bundled with.  We believe that ads are a legitimate way to monetize, but that they should be a known cost to the extension user."

So in this particular case at least, Google viewed it as acceptable, curiously both Kaspersky Labs and Microsoft Security Essentials reported this immediately to me as malware and removed the Extension.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking. An ad supported extension isn't evil. All the websites we visit everyday are ad supported. But I sense people have a negative feeling about them (and apparently security software too). This is why I am undecided about introducing ads in my extension, even though it has cost me a valuable amount of time to develop and maintain it,